# How to allow "Interact with desktop" in a service

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have created a simple VB.NET windows service. I have created a setup package and added the installer using design view -> add installer. I would like to allow this service to interact with the desktop. I am aware that you can go to "services" and allow interaction with the desktop but I would like to do it at install time. I have read many online articles but they refer to c# and the ones I have tried did not work. The way that I assume to do it is to edit the registry entry for the service.I have no real idea of what to do.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Check out the [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. When and how would I use the Service Controller? Do I include it in the custom actions for my installer?

Comment: You use it in a Windows Form and access the Service via this class. `WCF` is also a better Service to use these days as it is more flexible - though I have not used one for this purpose.